# FIFO queue with manual trigger

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a stream of notifications (source A), but I only want to show the user one notification at a time. Next notification will be presented when the user dismisses the previous one (manual trigger B)

So I need a FIFO queue like observable which emits only first item when another, manually triggered observable emits. Something like this:

```
A (data)    -> 'item1', ....., 'item2', ....., 'item3' .....

B (trigger) -> .........., trigger, ......, trigger, .....

expected output ->........., 'item 1', ...., 'item2' .....
```

Comment: Set up an Observable for A. Set up a second Observable for B. Use `withLatestFrom` as detailed here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom

Comment: Hi, withLatestFrom will skip c2 and c3 as in the example. And I need to emit them as well.

Comment: See the link you provided and the graph.

Comment: I have improved the question, hope they will reopen it soon.

Comment: Anyway, seems like zip is exactly what I am looking for. I thought this operator will emit an array of all values at once, but it matches it one by one. Thank you a lot :-)

Comment: I was able to get this question re-opened so I could post a better formatted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `zip`. It worked with my a simple example:

```
  private triggerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  trigger$ = this.triggerSubject.asObservable();

  data$ = from(sampleData);
  // Only emit items from the first stream (data$)
  // when the second stream emits (trigger$)
  action$ = zip(
    this.data$,
    this.trigger$.pipe(filter(value => Boolean(value)))
  ).pipe(
    // Only emit the item (not the trigger)
    map(([item, trigger]) => item)
  );

 doAction(): void {
    this.triggerSubject.next(true);
 }
```

This outputs the next item on each trigger action (a button click in my example).

Comment: Again thank you .  Zip was the way to go.